# How do I find the volume flow rate for a circular air duct?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, hvac

My assumption to solve this problem is to find the average velocity on each circle then get the average velocity between the 1st and 2nd circle and then find the volume flow rate between circle 1 and 2, and the same between the 3rd and 2nd circles, and 3rd and 4th circles. $$V_{avg})_{1-2}=\frac{V_{avg_1}+V_{avg_2}}{2}$$ then take $$\dot{Q}_{1-2}={V_{avg})_{1-2}}*(A_2-A_1)$$
$$V_{avg}=\frac{V_{avg_1}+V_{avg_2}+V_{avg_3}+0}{4}$$
$$\dot{Q}_{total}=\dot{Q}_{1-2}+\dot{Q}_{2-3}+\dot{Q}_{3-4}$$

Almost like changing the integrals in reynolds transformation to a summation but I'm unsure if this approach is correct.

[image]

Comment: Would this help: https://zeus.plmsc.psu.edu/~manias/MatSE447/04_FlowInVariedGeometries.pdf?

Comment: I think you need to take average flow rates for each circle, then do flow rates for each "donut" of the duct.  Remember that there is more area to further you go out in the radium.

Comment: after combining replicate measurements (i.e. at each radius), you have essentially 4 pairs of (r/R, flow). Since we don't know if turbulent or laminar or transition, seems you'd have to do a regression to fit to a general form of *r/R -> flow*, or alternatively determine from those whether you're in the turbulent or laminar regime and fit to a form of *r/R -> flow* that is more specific to the regime you've identified.